# Human verification strips accented chars from initial search in top right bar ?

Tags: bug, search, unicode

I've noticed that if I search for a word with an accented character from the top right search bar, the search is transposed to the result search bar and the accented character is missing (*allé* becomes *all*) and this affects the results accordingly; I add the missing character and reapply the search when this occurs; this occurs only after the *human verification* prompt appears.

Is it my setup (FF40.0.2 + DNT request + *NoScript* addon) ; is that normal behavior ?

Comment: I can reproduce the bug with the captcha losing the accents in an incognito window on Chrome 43.

Comment: Please post the part about search conflating accented characters as a separate feature request. There's an older [feature request on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133336/search-is-too-accent-sensitive) which seems to have been over-implemented: now search disregards accents altogether.

Comment: I didn't try without an incognito window because I'm logged in so I don't get a captcha. An incognito window was a way to try without being logged in and without extensions.